# Safest Way to Deny Access to All Files for Git Runner Service Account?

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions, gitlab

I have a GitLab Runner and my coworkers are worried commands like

- Remove-Item $SOME_FOLDER* -Recurse -Force

can be dangerous. For example, if the GitLab Runnier has admin privileges, then accidentally running this command might cause bad things to happen ☢️:

- Remove-Item C:\* -Recurse -Force

To fix this, I created a *local* service account.  For the purposes of this question, we can assume the account was named my_service_account.  I did not assign my_service_account to any groups.  In fact, I didn't even assign it to the users group.  I then gave my_service_account FULL CONTROL of the deployment directory.

Unfortunately, while my_service_account *does* seem to keep the GitLab Runner from nuking the entire host system with a command like:

- Remove-Item C:\* -Recurse -Force

it does *not* seem to keep the GitLab Runner from doing stupid stuff like this:

- echo "test" > c:\someExistingDir\someNewGarbageFile.txt

My mentor and I looked into this a bit and we found that we can keep the GitLab Runner from creating random files by applying the *deny* type to the FULL CONTROL basic permission on all directories we want to protect.  Unfortunately, we want to protect the entire system from this and *only* allow the GitLab Runner to write to the deployment directory.

So I tried applying a *deny* type to the FULL CONTROL basic permission on the entire C: drive, but when I started to use the MS Windows GUI to do that, it seemed to want to override the perms for a bunch of *other* users and groups like Administrators, SYSTEM, Users and Authenticated Users (See Picture):
[image]

**What is the easiest and safest way for me to DENY access to *all* system files for my_service_account without using the mentioned GUI which may result in "collateral damage"?**

NOTE: The GUI picture is actually from my Home PC and *not* the machine that hosts the GitLab Runner.  The picture is provided to illustrate the problem where the GUI insists I change the permissions for users and groups that are IMO out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest and safest way for me to DENY access to all system
> files...

You want to ensure the user account which the service is running or the context which the commands can run does not have local administrator permission to the system.

> I don't want to change the subfolder permissions for these users...

When you setup a new NTFS "**`deny`**" rule at the "**`C:\`"** level, you cannot really protect any beneath child files and folders unless you "**`Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries~`**" from that parent object which you are setting the new deny rule.

What you set at the parent level needs to be inherited and propagate to all child objects in order for those permission restrictions to become effective on the child objects as well.

Also note that even checking that option and allowing any new NTFS restrictive permissions to propagate to children object will not affect any folders or files which inheritance is explicitly unset or broken.

**To keep it simple**, I'd ensure the service account does not have local administrator access to the system, have good system backups and restore/recovery processes, and test running commands to try to break it.

Comment: Seems a windows equivalent of chroot might help limit the scope for me.

Comment: @ShawnEary I haven't had time to play with it, but https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview might be able to do the isolation you are seeking if you're working with Windows 10. I'm not sure how else Windows could "natively" isolate actions if the commands can be explicitly typed for anywhere on the underlying OS. I wish I had more time for playing with this feature to figure out what it takes to get it setup, documented, and iron out the correlated logic using PowerShell specifically as much as possible.